# Gulp plumber не останавливает асинхронные плагины

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, потоки-данных, асинхронность

Предположим, у меня есть таск, в котором используется gulp-plumber совместно с плагином, который работает через through2 и вызывает callback не сразу, а через какое-то время. Т.е. что-то вроде этого:

```
gulp.task('default', () => gulp
    .src('src/*')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(function() {
        return through2.obj(function(file, enc, next) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                next(new PluginError('test', 'error'));
            }, 1000);
        });
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('result'))
);
```

В таком случае срабатывает hanler plumber'a, однако таск не завершается:

```
Starting 'default'...
Error in "test" (1):
 PluginError: error
 // Информация об ошибке, то же, что и при синхронном вызове
The following tasks did not complete: default
Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Последние 2 строчки появляются только при завершении gulp'a. Если же я использую watch, то выводится только ошибка. Все просто останавливается, процесс не завершается, однако дальше ни один watch не работает.

Как исправить? Это проблема plumber'а, или в плагинах в принципе нельзя использовать подобные асинхронные вызовы? В таком случае, как же мне использовать такие "неправильные" плагины без падения gulp?